# Cannot add Navigation Drawer Activity in Xamarin.Android. After adding an activity, I cannot Navigate to that activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Android development. I want to add a Navigation activity in my app. I have also created a sample Project in Android Studio with Navigation Drawer Activities. I have created the same Scripts in Xamarin.Android (Visual Studio 2019-v16.3.2 with Xamarin v16.3.0.274). Hence I have created 2 Activities in Xamarin.Android just similar to Android Studio Project. In the Android Studio Project, I can Navigate from Main Activity to Other Activity without any problem, But If I Navigate from Main Activity to second activity, I get the error

> 'This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.'

Here is my **styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.companyname.weatherapp">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my second **Activity Layout (activity_favorites.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_favorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_favorites"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_favorites_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my **Second Activity Script (FavoritesActivity.cs)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Favorites")]
    public class FavoritesActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_favorites);

            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar); // HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR WHILE RUNNING: This Activity already has an action bar supplied...
            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, /*toolbar, */Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            View view = (View)sender;
            Snackbar.Make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LengthLong)
                .SetAction("Action", (View.IOnClickListener)null).Show();
        }

        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.nav_home)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_slideshow)
            { }
            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            this.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_favorites, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I am not getting any compile errors. I am getting this error whenever I Navigate to "Favorites" activity from MainActivity from Navigation drawer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need add the `AppTheme.NoActionBar` to your FavoritesActivity

like:

```
[Activity(Label = "Favorites", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar")]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`